# Twig render with vars

Tags: render, twig

I'm using Silex, and need to alter a Twig file based on the location its loaded from.

My first thought was checking the url, but unfortunately this returns the location of the rendered Twig location, and not the parent url as expected.

```
{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route')) }}
```

Another attempt was to pass some vars with the render, however I'm not certain how to do this from within Twig (and if it's possible at all).

```
{{ render(path('cart')) }}
```

Can someone possible help me with a solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a problem with silex core. I have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/pull/524) that introduces a new `renderRoute` twig function that should fix the issue. Hopefully it will be merged soon.

Answer (score 0):

Well i didn't get perfectly what are you asking, but if you want to pass variables in render method you can do this:

```
{% render "ProjectTesteBundle::ControllerName::actionName" with { 'variableNameToPass' : variableValue } %}
```

if you want get route name in twig template you can do do something like this:

```
{% set routeName = app.request.attributes.get('_route') %}
```

Comment: {{ render(path('cart')) with { 'variableNameToPass' : '123' } }}

Twig_Error_Syntax: Unexpected token "name" of value "with" ("end of print statement" expected) in "checkout.html.twig" at line 22

Comment: imagine this: You have a class controller = TesteController.php ;<br/> inside this class you have a method = mymethodAction($variableNameToPass) ; <br/> if you use the definition i used in my answer you have acess in that method to the value that you pass in template. Now you can do whatever you want with that value, for example, pass it to a view. <br/> read this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

Comment: I'm using Silex, the micro-framework based on Symfony2. Silex is not based on using Controllers.

Comment: well in that case i cant help